# How to make cloud web application work offline like android

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, cloud

We have a cloud based web application in angular 8 and asp.net mvc 5 and uses mysql as database. 
Currently, our application is online means it does not work without internet. User performs CRUD operations and that gets saved on cloud server and whenever required user gets data from cloud server for view purpose.

My problem is, some of our customers don't have internet. So how can i make my web application run offline also like android mobile applications does. Means i will save data in local DB and may be after every  30 seconds i will sync this local database to my cloud server MYSQL database. Can i use sq-lite for this?  and how to save data in local server and sync to MySQL database on cloud server.
OR what is the best way to develop this kind of application.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. Web applications are running on web. That means that they require internet connection. Android apps are running on OS. That leads to conclusion that to achieve this you have to develop desktop or mobile app that will have the same functions as your web app. Operations can be stored to local database and synced with main database with api calls.

Now probably the question is "Is there a magic tool to transform web app to desktop or mobile app automatically". The answer is NO.